# Is feminism necessarily trans-exclusionary?

Tags: mind-body, feminism

Transgender rights and feminism in the US are both considered part of the cultural left's causes, but it occurred to me that one might perceive an inherent tension between the two:

- The basis of feminism seems, to me, that all differences between men and women other than anatomical differences are purely social constructs. Women don't have inherently different intellects and emotional dispositions than men, and whatever differences they do have are acquired characteristics inculcated by  a patriarchal society. Moreover a lot of traditionally feminine behavior, such as dressing a certain way, an acceptance of objectification, etc...are linked to the oppression of women.
- Trans folk on the other hand are stereotyped as "feeling like a trapped [man/woman] in a [woman/man]'s body", "knowing since early childhood that they were really women", etc...as if gender and sex are separate notions. It's almost as if they're embracing a form of mind-body dualism, with there being a specific gendered mind that then has to be correctly synced up with a gendered body.

How can one reconcile feminist ideals with transgender notions of what really makes a person male or female? And does being trans indeed imply a form of mind-body dualism if claims of belonging to one gender but being trapped in the wrong body are valid?

Comment: I'm busy at the moment but your question is founded in a complete misunderstanding and pernicious misrepresentation of what it means to be transgender. Transfolk do not often speak that way, it's a stereotype. Most transfolk do not have the experience from childhood that you describe - they realize later on. There *is* more to being a woman than anatomy, at least neurologically ([just one example](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10508-016-0850-z)). And many/most transfolk don't embrace gender roles; that's a complete misconception.

Comment: ...there's in fact a double-standard for transfolk: if you don't embrace the gender roles, how can you really be trans? But if you do, aren't you just keeping the institutional inequalities in place? Feminism understands that this is what transfolk have to face, and seeks to overcome the ignorance your question exemplifies.

Comment: This is all not even to mention that your question erases the existence of non-binary transfolk, who constitute a sizeable (in my experience, at least a quarter) proportion of the trans population. Sorry, I guess I wasn't that busy - just too busy to dig up references right now.

Comment: "The basis of feminism is that all differences between men and women other than anatomical differences are purely social constructs" -- I think that is one branch or interpretation of feminism, a somewhat extremist or academic position.

Comment: @commando a) I know I'm ignorant, that's why I ask. b) "Transfolk do not often speak that way," -- my information is anecdotal, collected from news articles and social media posts, but every single one of them spoke of being trapped in a body of the wrong gender, and many spoke of knowing since childhood. If you can point me to better sources, I'd bet grateful. c) The question isn't "how can you be trans if you don't embrace gender roles?", it's "how can you be trans if there is no such a thing as gender role?"

Comment: @commando also saying that there inherent neurological differences is one step away from saying that women don't have the right neural structure to be soldiers or mathematicians or what not.

Comment: @AlexanderSKing a) and yet you've stated your incorrect generalizations as offensive facts; b) I haven't stumbled upon studies of this and I'd be surprised if they were conducted, but as a participant in the queer community with almost a dozen trans friends and an order of magnitude more interactions, I daresay I'm speaking from an epistemically superior position...

Comment: ...c) gender and gender roles are not the same thing. There are neurological accounts of gender (e.g. [1](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/is-there-something-unique-about-the-transgender-brain/), see [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuroscience_of_sex_differences)) which do not commit to gender roles. They commit only to the reality of the gender dysphoria/euphoria transfolk face, and the necessity of treating that appropriately. The treatment is not to put someone in the "right" role. It's to provide them with whatever they need to relieve dysphoria (usually hormone therapy)

Comment: You latest comment is completely off the mark. It's not a normative claim. It's the claim that being transgender is a robust medical condition with robust requirements for treatment, and that being transgender is entirely separate from a *social* notion of gender roles or any such anti-feminist claim. I don't see how that edges even close to prescribing inabilities to women.

Comment: [here](https://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/laugh-cry-live/201509/are-transgender-women-just-reinforcing-sexist-stereotypes) [are](http://everydayfeminism.com/2015/03/trans-people-gender-essentialism/) [a](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/kelsie-brynn-jones/transexclusionary-radical-terf_b_5632332.html) [few](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feminist_views_on_transgender_and_transsexual_people) [sources](http://everydayfeminism.com/2014/02/trans-inclusive-feminist-movement/)

Comment: Thanks for the sources. I've dug up an [opposing point of view](http://www.nytimes.com/2015/06/07/opinion/sunday/what-makes-a-woman.html?emc=edit_tnt_20150606&nlid=55025100&tntemail0=y&_r=1) and surprisingly, the [SEP mentions the question as well](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/feminism-trans/) "*One major set of philosophical themes concerns competing conceptions of the self and its relation to the sexed body and to gender [...] Is the self prior to the institution of gender identity? Is sex the “hardware” on which the program of gender is run, or is sex itself thoroughly cultural?*"

Comment: I never said that men and women have necessarily different brains. I never said that the trans experience is the cis experience. The article is founded in a misunderstanding I haven't the time to explain before my impending class, but in brief: all I said was the transgender experience is medically validated. There *is* such a thing as a subtly, slightly different trans brain. And that's enough to validate the experience. The author of that article is naively taking this to be some sort of equivocation. And mention of a question is not the same as its being a good one.

Comment: Even accepting the contested claims I do not see how verbal reports projected back to early childhood contradict social construction of gender (be it true or false). At most they would show that society occasionally "inculcates" psychological inclinations at odds with biological gender already in early childhood. And this is taking them at face value, which is itself highly dubious because complex notions acquired later in life ("feeling like a woman") are imputed to the tender age where they can hardly be expected to be operational.

Comment: Isn't this a question for politics or psychology? That you request of the respect for obtaining knowledge (read: philosophy) the reconciliation of two ways of looking at things you will neither obtain knowledge nor discover anything more than further weltanschauung. If a way of looking at things were adequate to obtain knowledge, then you could drink from a mirage while confusing it for oasis. You can not.

Comment: The trans-exclusionary radical feminists (TERFs) have made exactly that point. http://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Trans-exclusionary_radical_feminism

Comment: @Alexander S King, that's a great question, and mentioned in SEP too because it IS relevant, and I'm surprised by hostility shown by Commando, instead of admitting that this IS a problem that people in the two movements are facing and that as a result of interaction between these movements different themes are being pursued to clarify each movement's position and see to what extent a middle ground can be reached. The only issue I have is the word "inherently" in OP's question and I want to say feminism has many branches/waves and that view is not inherent to them all.

Comment: From my admittedly small experience, I don't think it is fair to say that the claims about early experiences of transexuality are inexistent or even rare. In fact, I have more than once asked, "but isn't it true that there is such thing as late onset transexuality", and seem to have got my interlocutors confused, as if the notion was alien to them. On the other hand I don't think that we need to take verbal reports of anyone about their own psychologic histories in order to be respectful of their personalities.

Comment: @gonzo you will note that the phrase was King's. I simply left it untouched. The classical, obsolete position is synonymity of gender and sex. The intermediate, progressing notion is that they are different. The progressed realization is that sex is an unnecessary construction since its ostensible biological foundations are inconsistent (see intersexuality, androgen insensitivity, genetic mosaicism, etc.), and that gender is all we can really rely on. Which brings to the foreground the difficult notion of defining gender. We should avoid more comments on this chain.

Comment: @gonzo if I were to correct the question's biases completely it would call for a total rewrite from scratch. I preserved the implicit binary among other things to maintain some semblance of the original, out-dated tone.

Comment: I thought this essay might interest you: https://quillette.com/2019/01/02/strange-bedfellows-the-peculiar-alliance-between-centrist-liberals-and-radical-feminists/

Comment: Here's an essay that addresses the concerns of your original post in the context of what has transpired in the epistemic neighborhood over the past half decade: https://quillette.com/2021/09/12/judith-butler-enough-already/

Answer (score 15):

It seems to me that this question is based upon two false assumptions.

1.) Feminism today seeks not to erase the differences between men and women, but to change the perception of everything feminine as being inherently lesser than everything masculine. It is from this aim to normalize and appreciate "femininity" that the lines between strictly gendered values may appear to blur, such as the realization that crying does not indicate weakness leading to an acceptance of men crying instead of being forced by social obligation to hide their feelings. Modern feminism acknowledges that there may be differences between men and women, but that those differences do not interfere with our abilities to be useful, functional, and rational. In the past, the main struggle was to prove that women were even capable of becoming "soldiers and mathematicians and whatnot," as you mentioned, and as a result were forced to present themselves in a more masculine way; in order to be taken seriously, a woman in a predominantly male field had to present herself as "one of the guys" to be accepted. Now, the women in those positions are seeking the freedom to reclaim their femininity (however they define it) because things like wearing makeup and watching soap operas don't affect a person's ability to think logically and work diligently. The idea here is to paint the traditional view of  femininity in a more positive light in order to share it with men (as wearing makeup and watching soap operas have no power to reflect on the validity of a man's gender and do not inherently weaken a person) and break the requirement of women to completely conform to this traditional feminine role.

2.) The "popular transgender narrative," as it is referred to within the queer and trans community, was created to simplify the trans experience into something easily digested by cisgender people. The idea that somebody can be "a woman trapped in a man's body" is outlandish and ridiculous, but I am guilty of providing a similar simplification as explanation of my decision to transition to those that I already know will never understand my feelings. The actual trans experience consists of a combination of social and physical dysphoria that may arise at any time in one's life, and is usually not understood until much later in life. We are forced to claim that we knew from birth in order to dodge invalidating accusations that something "turned" us transgender, even if we didn't begin questioning our gender until our teens, thirties, or late sixties. Social dysphoria can be defined most simply as the discomfort experienced from being forced into the roles associated with the gender that one is assigned at birth (which feminism seeks to dismantle), whether one is given the opportunity to explore the feeling of living within the role of another gender or not. Physical dysphoria, similarly simplified, is the discomfort or disgust felt in regards to one's body in terms of not only secondary sex characteristics, but often things such as height, body type, and facial features. Whether this discomfort is a result of subconscious associations with social values regarding the binary gendered body (as those who support the complete abolition of gender will claim) remains to be seen, and the concrete, physical discomfort will not be soothed by this kind of realization anyways. The adaptation of traditional gender roles after transition is often another attempt to dodge invalidation, and many transfolk do experience a more mixed identification with certain aspects of their assigned gender and of their true gender.

As a transman and a feminist, I believe that modern feminism only stands to improve the social acceptance of genderqueer and transgender people due to the overlap of issues that feminism seeks to resolve and struggles that genderqueer and transfolk face.

Comment: This is really well said, and I appreciate your being so forthcoming. Honestly, I don't understand why anyone gives a rip about gender roles, or any kind of roles at all. I don't know why people care what other people think, feel, want or whatever. Just avoid people you don't get along with. It can't mathematically be everyone, so damn everyone else. And this word 'assigned' is really incorrect. There was no *assignment* going on. No one was is charge, is in charge or ever will be. You are tall, fat, orange or whatever and that is just as random as anything else in the universe. So what?

Comment: "We are forced to claim that we knew from birth" - I haven't heard people say that, because we don't know anything at birth, but I have heard people say that they *were* trans from birth, or at least as long as they can remember, with various anecdotes to support that (although it may have taken varying amounts of time to figure that, and to find the words to express it, especially when/where the idea of being trans was/is still relatively unknown in society). That may not be the case for everyone, but it's certainly the case for plenty of trans people.

Answer (score 2):

This may be less of an answer than a defense of the question -- I like @AlexanderSKing and I consider him more brave than misinformed.  My own reaction is exactly @Oliver's, and I don't intend to compete with him.

The question leaves out a very important complicating factor.  There really are three players in the game here.  Framings of gay identity, transgender understandings and different kinds of feminism all compete to shape our assumptions about gender in definite and permanent ways.  In the process, they all step on one another's toes to one degree or another.  Pretending they all happily get along lies somewhere between posturing and wishful thinking.  Here is one cycle of conflicts that have yet to be reconciled.

It is primarily the stability of the understanding upon which the broader society has accepted gay culture that relies strongly on gender roles being largely socially constructed, with inborn nature not matching the social construction.  Feminism only gains from this perspective when women want a chance to play men's roles, not when they want to be valued for themselves and truly integrated into an equal society that acknowledges the full range of natural behaviors.

Feminism focussed on the latter: increasing the real social value of women as they already contribute to society, without becoming any more like men, also exists.  And it contains branches that adopt basic gender differences traceable to physical differences as a positive fact we have not yet adequately valued.  (E.g. Dianic Witches and the likes of Christina Hoff-Summers)  We have never truly cultivated natural female (or male) nature because we have overlayed it with a bias toward the demands of social roles.  To my mind they are right, but this returns certain gay men to the position of being inadequately male at a basic level.

The casualties of this conflict turn to history and identify a historical trend of maintaining a 'psychologically hermaphroditic' sex or 'third gender' of effeminate males, often as a marked variety of priest, and often placing them in the roles of confessor, arbitrator or ambassador. (E.g. , "The Zuni Two-Spirit" a' la Ambassador We'Wha, the Hermaphrodyte imagery in Alchemy, half of all Marian Orders of Franciscan Priests.)

Transgender advocates can just look at that and accuse those men of being self-hating transgendered individuals who cannot own their identity because they have been afforded a place due to male privilege.

Other gay men obviously don't want to see a contingent of people who would rather identify with them rather than apart from them further degraded by what they see as aggressive political correctness.  So they more strongly cling to the notion that all of this is about other people trying to impose an identity on them.  They often go too far with this, to the degree that they deny the validity or extent of claims about intersexual/intergender identity.

And around and around we go...

Dynamics like this are real and matter to those trapped in them.  So having outsiders point them out is not a horrible thing that needs to be beaten away with a stick.

Comment: Sorry, but the "three players are?  "Queers" (meaning gays?), "feminists",  and  "transfolk"?    And what does"Other gay men obviously don't want to see a contingent of people who would rather identify with them rather than apart from them further degraded by what they see as aggressive political correctness. So they lean into the notion that all of this is about other people trying to impose an identity on them, to the degree that they infringe on valid claims as to the extent of intersexual identity" mean?

Comment: @gonzo.  I have added some detail, broken up some overcomplicated sentences, and removed some colloquialisms.  I hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: Pointing out tension brought about by misunderstanding differs from making a strong claim that two positions are necessarily contradictory, and doing so offensively. The original (unedited) question was not nearly so innocently probing or merely suggestive as your reading implies (and it remains problematic). I can't reply to your other comments within this comment, and somehow I doubt that whatever I say will be to your satisfaction. But what was being asked did not have the value you suggest. Engaging in that level of discourse implies a pre-existing understanding which was not demonstrated.

Comment: @commando  I still feel you are imputing malice where stupidity suffices.  I am not in any way implying the author has the breadth of perspective on this issue that people who have to navigate the issue first hand.  But this kind of problem is all a deeper network of exactly the same contradictions those never challenged by any of this face when they encounter these issues.  If we still can't make sense to one another, we should take better perspective on the rest of the people to whom we make no sense.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, it looks like I miscommunicated. I never meant to impute malice - only ignorance. But ignorance isn't precluded from my accusations of perniciousness, and my frustration stems in large from the fact that asking such a "brave" question seems like a great deal of misplaced effort. It's essentially a request to be spoon-fed information, whereas taking the ten seconds to google "transgender feminism" will immediately yield a half-dozen relevant results. This isn't to mention the incorrigibility of the asker in response to my comments. If one's opinion is already formed, why ask?

Comment: @commando -- I have a bizarre past, and I certainly know Dianic witches and radical Faeries who totally doubt the authenticity of M-to-Fs, and propose shallow psychological theories of them as overprivileged males with bizarre envy issues, and I know transsexuals who try to tell inter-gendered people who prefer to identify as bisexual men that this is a cowardly betrayal, etc.  This stuff is complicated and for some reason that ultimately makes no sense, it all just hurts.  Adding extra defensiveness is somehow automatic.

Comment: You're right, of course. And I'm sure your experiences eclipse mine. I'm still a young person coming to terms with my queerness, and in such a vulnerable situation it was hurtful to see the question, especially as first phrased, on a site for which I feel a certain familial affiliation. I stand by my words - but I grant that they came from a place of layered protectiveness.

Comment: @commando  And to my eyes, it seems to me that you are the one with the overdeveloped theories that you won't see questioned, addressing someone wholly unused to even thinking about this.  The theoretical bases behind gay/trans/feminist identity politics and the science that support them are still very weak for the quantity of assertions made.

Comment: My primary claim being the innocuousness of the trans identity amidst feminism, I'm not sure I see your point. The borders of my claims are subject to dispute, but my core assertion was simple, pre-scientific, and echoed by Oliver: the line of thought motivating trans-exclusionary rhetoric is founded in a misunderstanding of what constitutes the trans experience (viz. trans folk ostensibly adhering to certain insidious beliefs and social practices by necessity). Scientific evidence is just a cherry on top of that reality.

Comment: Sorry, we overlapped there.  But ultimately, your generation has a theoretical basis and a breadth of support that mine lacked, so this kind of conversation will hopefully be less vicious, and more fact-based.  But perspective must be maintained.  A lot of 'facts' about these subjects are terrilby finely filtered by political correctness, and ultimately not as convincing as they need to be.

Comment: But this is ultimately psychology, and psychological 'facts' based in taking experience as it is given have been used to uphold racism, force conversions to religions, etc. as well.  Documenting an experience does not ensure it is not caused by social manipulation.

Comment: I am sorry that I am in the habit of beating up on people for not listening.  You have seen where it has gotten me with others.  And I hope you do take this for what it is.  A request that you consider the frailty of those around you, and not an attempt to control how you think.

Comment: If I've understood correctly, our agreement-in-fact is overshadowed by a methodological criticism you're making of me. I suspect this takes us to nuances on the context of the discourse not quite worth the rabbit hole. I should presumably stop here, since this is something we could easily discuss for aeons. But I think we're on the same page - or, at least, reading the same chapter.

Comment: @commando -- Surely.  And sorry to keep with the addendums... But one more:  I also want to back away from 'trumping' your experience.  I am just a gay guy whose actual experience of coming out has been relatively untraumatic, and who could easily have been asexual my entire life.  But I have been very close to folks who eventually identified as transsexual and/or intergendered in the context of a religious circle that forced a high level of emotional honesty.  So my experience is all empathy and no real investment.  That probably makes it easier for me to be academic about it all.

Comment: Jobermark thanks for defending me. @commando thanks for the edit, I acknowledge that my original formulation of the question was somewhat offensive - as it was based on popular media accounts of the topic, not any direct knowledge of the community involved. I asked the question here exactly because I felt it was safe place where the audience understands that questioning philosophical assumptions doesn't necessarily imply some form of bigotry.

Comment: I thought this essay might be of interest:  https://quillette.com/2019/01/02/strange-bedfellows-the-peculiar-alliance-between-centrist-liberals-and-radical-feminists/

Comment: and around... and around

Comment: **Almost every part of this answer is egregiously factually incorrect.** 1. The framing that gay, trans and feminist people are in conflict when the same people usually advocate for all 3 (never mind gay trans feminists). 2. Implying that feminism is primarily about "when women want a chance to play men's roles", and feminists who want equality "also exist", even though the literal definition of feminism is about equality. 3. "Branches" of feminism may look down on being gay, but those hardly speak for the majority. 4. History is more complicated than the narrative you're trying to spin here.

Comment: 5. Trans advocates don't commonly accuse people of being self-hating, and you saying they cite male privilege just seems like pure conspiracy theory. 6. Your point about gay people feeling "degraded" by the existence of trans people only makes sense if you equate being gay and being trans, yet they're obviously very different. 7. If anything needs to be "beaten away with a stick" it's people trying to argue that others shouldn't be allowed to exist, and supporting that with false and incoherent arguments like those in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

If the defining concept of trans theory, “Gender dysphoria”, is  defined as “the condition of feeling one's emotional and psychological identity as male or female to be opposite to one's biological sex,”  and if the referenced “feeling” denotes a discrepancy between one’s behavioral predispositions and the behavioral dispositions deemed appropriate by one'ssociety/culture to one’s biological gender (the supposedly socially constructed gender role of one’s biological gender), then there would seem to be some contradiction between transgenderism and feminism as you have defined it (the traditional definition).

If, however, with Commando,  that “feeling” of dysphoria instead denotes somehow “experiencing” the neurological difference between a cis and a trans brain (see Commando’s comment and citation to a Scientific American article: “There are neurological accounts of gender (e.g. 1,) which do not commit to gender roles.”), then there need be no contradiction.   However, the cited article would seem to open a can of worms.   For what the article seems to imply  is that there are four materially different brains (or brain types):  cis male, cis female, trans male and trans female.  If so, then it makes sense to reconsider whether “gender roles” are in fact social constructs or something else. (Moreover, such a scenario also addresses you “mind-body”  problem by rendering it moot -- it is body (read brain) all the way down.)

Comment: Your answer adheres to the anachronistic gender binary. There are plenty of gender non-binary transfolk. The dichotomy between "male" and "female" as opposed is false. Nor is the conclusion as you say it is: gender theory needn't commit itself to neurological essentialism as you describe, but merely the essentialism that there is a trans* variation in neurology. As for the first paragraph: this is just not how gender theory works. I could try and cite individual pieces but I think it's more productive to cite the field as such.

Comment: I'd also like to point out that your language of antecedent "if" clauses presupposes there's a question of the matter. We've had comments on the original question presuming this is the case, but they're comparable to a Renaissance cardinal's supposition that Copernican astronomy is subject to debate. I implore those involved in this question to educate themselves thoroughly on the matter at hand. It will become clear, as Oliver's answer indicates, that there is no case to be made for a problem. All existing arguments rely on misinterpretation or misrepresentation.

Comment: @commando  I think you are being overly defensive here and attempting to shut down competing discourse.  The subjective accounts of people are not necessarily philosophical facts, and we do not have to give them any more weight than we would give sightings of ghosts.  You need to keep within your context and own your alignment with a given philosophical position if you are going to judge others on the same standard.  Besides, "If the sky is blue" is not an offensive position.  Asking questions is not taking positions.

Comment: @jobermark that strikes me as naive. A proper appraisal of the philosophical facts is what will demonstrate the invalidity of the subjective positions I'm criticizing while inundating those I'm supporting with philosophical weight. I never said that the trans experience is valid by virtue of being an experience. But a rudimentary observation of the facts will reveal how misinformed the trans-exclusionary rhetoric in fact is, and to do this it's important to take into account the trans experience, since the argument is itself founded in claims about what it is to be trans.

Comment: @commando  If I am being naive, I would still need more than your word on that.  What you are doing is much like atheists telling the religious they are crazy.  Facts are only facts if they have context on which to rely.  People who feel alien in their bodies and choose to take that as a natural variation within their gender still deserve a voice.

Comment: There is a point at which transgender activists start telling off effeminate men who fight to enlarge the space afforded to men to be non-conforming socially as not having the 'guts' to claim an intersexual identity.  Everyone has their agenda, and we need to not take our own agenda as fact until we really have the facts.

Comment: Ever since the debates elicited, or exacerbated,  by Thomas Kuhn, Copernican astronomy is always the poster child for this kind of discussion in the philosophy of science.  But few propositions of science are as immune to revision.   What we are dealing with here is more akin to evolutionary biology, no?   While mostly settled (no competing theories for now) ,  evolutionary biology is in a much more dynamic state -- the skeleton is there, but much needs to be fleshed in.   The point is that many of these questions are not [completely] settled…

Comment: …For instance, if it turns out true that there exist substantial biological/neurological differences between cis male, cis female, trans male and trans female brains, then the question reasonably arises: are there functional differences as well, differences which correspond to the biology?   Or do they shed any light on, the Wittgensteinian “grammer”, or “form of life”  that gives rise to our evolving gender talk?

Comment: @gonzo  Note we have now adopted the context of General Relativity, and idea that everything exists in its own frame of reference, so it is quite reasonable from the Earth's perspective that the Sun goes around it.   Facts always have a context.  Even Copernicanism.  In this case, brain structure arguments are seldom convincing to many social constructivists in general because even if there are functional differences, we still cannot tell cause from effect.  Biology represents development which is shaped by stresses and expectations as much as genes.

Comment: I understand that the proverbial nurture v nature question (although you kinda strike me as being way too young to appreciate the issue phrased this way) has never and will likely never be conclusively resolved.  However, the brain structure/neurological/biological argument as a description/identification of trangenerism was introduced by Comando, not I.

Comment: 1. @Commando:  You said:  “Your answer adheres to the anachronistic gender binary. There are plenty of gender non-binary transfolk. The dichotomy between "male" and "female" as opposed is false.”  I apologize for my ignorance and or perceived disrespect.  The definition I cited was lifted from an internet dictionary.  Nevertheless although I understand the notion of  non-binary gender roles, I cannot make sense of non-binary “gender” (‘hermaphrodites” aside), since that term is reputed to be synonymous with the term ”sex,”  generally defined in terms of reproductive functions...

Comment: 3. Even androgeny is defined in terms of gender roles, not gender:  “Androgyne:  An individual who feels they do not properly fit into the gender roles ascribed by society to males and females. Often feels as though their gender is beyond the understanding of these limiting societal factors and seeks to free themselves from that which limits them by dress in androgynous clothing and attempting to appear on the outside as they feel on the inside.”...

Comment: ...As defined, is are “Androgyne” distinct from “transfolk.”  Again , forgive the ignorance.  I am inexperienced with these new ontological types/ metaphysical categories.

Comment: @gonzo To some degree don't purposive androgynes *have* to be *transvestites* if they are purposely avoiding their own genders prescribed dress (even if they avoid the others')?  If they carry the same logic out to other dimensions then, yes, a lot of people consider inter-gendered statuses like androgyny, asexuality, 'the genderfucked' who purposely mix and mock both sets of gender prescriptions, &c, to be transfollk.  In given cases historically, 'female-assigned' gay men and eunuchs have been considered a separate gender where 'male-assigned' gay men have been seen as men with odd tastes.

Comment: @gonzo  Especially since the results of F-to-M surgical procedures are either not yet satisfactory in what is possible, or are satisfactory to the person adapting to a large enough degree well before the point they would endanger the ability to enjoy sex, and a lot of F-to-M transsexuals therefore still have functioning female genitalia, and may not even lose the uterus, if they can be OK and avoid surgery "trans" ness does not involve going "all the way over", only far enough to escape the specific content of a given individual's gender dysphoria.

Comment: @commando: I thought this essay might be of interest , though, unfortunately, you will be unable to take it upon yourself to edit it to conform with your ideology: https://quillette.com/2019/01/02/strange-bedfellows-the-peculiar-alliance-between-centrist-liberals-and-radical-feminists/

Comment: Based on what I've heard from biologists and read in studies, I'd say the brains of cis men and trans men (female at birth) are similar / the same. But even if that's not the case, there certainly aren't "four brains", given that gender is a spectrum (what you said completely fails to account for the existence of non-binary people, or you just reject that entirely). It only "opens a can of worms" if you expect/require reality to conform to your strict categories. Most people who've taken at least an intermediate science/biology course will tell you how little of reality has neat categories.

Comment: @NotThatGuy:  While it has been far too long since I wrote this to reconstruct my then thought process, allow me to tell, in broad brushstrokes, what I-think-I-think today. 1st, my reference to “four brains” reductio ad absurdum-ish  (look it up).  2nd, what I believe is immaterial to how the universe is or is not.   But to put it succinctly, if I understand what the prefix “trans” means and what  "gender” means, I believe with my heart and soul that the concept “gender,” is on a continuum, is not “binary.”  In fact, I believe we are all, to a greater or lesser extent, on that continuum.

Comment: @NotThatGuy: Remember this has to do with how one “identifies”—ie about what one believes about oneself.  Sex, on the other hand, is a different ball of wax.  Not being a biologist, I do not know what it would even mean to but that concept, as I intuit it, on a continuum.   In this context, speaking of biology courses, maybe you should have a look at the recent claims made by the eminent evolutionary biologist Richard Dawkins (who has likely taken one or two “intermediate science/biology courses;  again, look him etc. up).  And, BTW, don’t sell yourself short, methinks you are that guy.

Comment: @NotThatGuy:  I note that in the 1st comment above I omitted the word "is" between “four brains” and "reductio ad absurdum-ish" .  What I meant was that my reference to four brains was a reductio ad absurdum-ish argument.  In the 2nd comment I said  I do not know what it would even mean to but that concept,  when what I meant to say is that  Not being a biologist, I do not know what it would even mean to PUT that concept [sex], as I intuit it, on a continuum.  Sorry for the typos.   Too late to edit, so I thought I'd just clarify.

Comment: @gonzo I know reductio ad absurdums, but this reads more like a strawman. You said "the article seems to imply" something that doesn't align with scientific consensus, nor common pro-trans views. If you want to present a reductio ad absurdum, you should be clear about what is actually said or implied, versus what inferences you're making based on that. When citing 1 article, we should also keep in mind that there's an entire body of research on the topic, of varying quality (people frequently cite one particular "scientific" article of someone surveying people to diagnose third parties).

Comment: @gonzo As for sex, you can define that in terms of gametes, genitals, chromosomes, brain structure, and other things. A person can be classified differently depending on the criteria. There isn't a "right" classification. We try to fit reality into neat little boxes, and doing so is often useful. But reality is also often messy, and we shouldn't put our little boxes on pedestals and say that because a particular fact of reality doesn't fit into those boxes, it therefore must be false.

Comment: Seems to me, @NotThatGuy, that we are going to have to agree to disagree on this one.  Nevertheless, I encourage you to have a look at evolutionary biologist Richard Dawkin's take on these issues.  Not that it will likely change your mind about anything, but it might help you tighten up your argument.